# Failed building wheel for snowflake-connector-python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

While running "pip install dbt-snowflake==1.5.5" command in command prompt I came across following error:
Failed to build snowflake-connector-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for snowflake-connector-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Some sources are instructing me to downgrade the Python version to 3.6 to run this command.

Some sources are instructing me to downgrade the Python version to 3.6 to run this command.

Comment: This package supports Python 3.8-3.11. Not sure who's 'instructing' you to downgrade to 3.6. Also, are you using `pip install dbt-snowflake==1.5.5` because of your requirements? `pip install dbt-snowflake` will install the latest version dbt-snowflake 1.7.1

Comment: My Python version is 3.11 but still giving the same error.

Comment: see if this helps https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/pip-install